# Async/Await Error when Taking Screenshot in Python Using Playwright: 'signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter'

Tags: flask, android-asynctask

I'm currently working on a Python web application where I need to take a screenshot of a user-provided URL using Playwright in an async function. I'm encountering an issue with asynchronous execution that I can't seem to resolve. Here's the code snippet:

```
async def embed_url():
    url = request.args.get('url')
    
    try:
        screenshot_path = await take_screenshot(url)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': f'Error taking screenshot: {e}'}), 500

    # ... Other code ...

async def take_screenshot(url):
    try:
        browser = await launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.newPage()
    
        await page.goto(url)
        path = '/public/images/website_screenshots/screen.png'
    
        await page.screenshot({'path': path, 'fullPage': True})
    
        await browser.close()
        return path
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:

"Error taking screenshot: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter"

i tried to use

```
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(take_screenshot(url))
```

but i got

```
"Error taking screenshot: This event loop is already running",
```